# ValueError while trying to split line extracted from file

Tags: python

```
with open(st) as file:

    for line in file:

        line = line.rstrip()

        name, species, homeworld = line.split("\t")

        characters.append(StarWarsCharacter(name, species, homeworld))
```

I'm trying to extract data, but I just get a value error:

```
ValueError:
name, species, homeworld = line.split("\t")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: maybe try `name, species, homeworld = line.split()` - hard to know for sure without the input file

Comment: Please show a (short) sample file that generates this error, and make this a complete, self-contained [MRE]. (Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! The [tour] and [ask] are good places to get started.)

Comment: `split()` returns a list of spitted strings. So, you can store the spitted strings in list, check the size of list and if it is more than 3, it means input is not right. And if its 3 you can store those 3 elements in your `characters` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the name of the file should be a string, the it should be `"st"`. Second, the error is clear: it means that the split returns only one token, but you expected 3. Then, the file you are trying to read is not separated by `"\t"`. In fact, trying to reproduce:

**script.py**:

```py
with open("st") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        ame, species, homeworld = line.split("\t")
```

Note that i didnt include the last line because I don't have these structs.

**st**:

```
pluto   dog homeworld
```

Running the command `python script.py` i don't have any error, because my file is correctly separated by `"\t"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting that each line **can** be split into 3 parts based on the separator `\t`.
But if it is not true you will get this error.

Additionally as commented by CrazyChucky, this can also happen if the line is empty.

Consider this example:

```
line = "a; b; c"
p1, p2, p3 = line.split(';')
p1, p2, p3 = line.split(',') # ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

The line cannot be split into three part based on the separator `,`.

Comment: Would also happen if even a single line is blank.